# Unclear return type for function taking eigen types as parameters

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to use the Eigen3 library in a scientific program but I'm struggling to make some simple functions and member functions. For example, I'm not certain what kind of return type should I choose for something like the following:

```
template <typename DerivedA,typename DerivedB>
inline **something** mult(const MatrixBase<DerivedA>& p1,
                          const MatrixBase<DerivedB>& p2)
  {
  return p1*p2;
  }
```

I assume that there is some class, say `productOp`, that I could return without a problem. I still could not imagine what would happen in a function involving a large number of operations, or even worse, an iteration that depends on the input:

```
template <typename Derived>
**something** foo(const MatrixBase<Derived>& p1))
  {
  **something** p2;
  p2.setZero();
  while(p2(0,0) < 1)
    p2 += p1; 
  return p2;
  }
```

My questions are:

1. Is the second example even possible?
2. How can I figure the type of an operation like `p1*p2`?
3. How can I figure the return type in the case of elaborate functions?

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  If you have C++14 available then you can just use `auto`.

Comment: Oh, in the documentation they recommend not using auto. Is this a good case for it?

Comment: hmm.  If it is an expression template then `auto` might not be the way to go.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you should not use auto with Eigen because some matrix operations result in non-matrix types that I assume are implicitly casted or handled in operator overloads. Therefore, if you declare it auto and always store the result in a non-auto variable, it will probably be ok. But, do you want to introduce a potential pitfall? Why are you even defining templates for already defined Eigen operations?

Comment: Those were just simple examples. They are really pointless.

Comment: If you want better answer regarding point 3, you should be more specific. E.g., do the Scalar type and dimensions of the returned matrix depend non-trivially on the parameters?

Comment: @chtz thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, returning `auto` will works well because it is a single expression that does not reference any local temporary.

In the second, you need to create and return an actual matrix/vector with its own storage, for instance:

```
typename Derived::PlainObject p2;
p2.resizeLike(p1);
```

and the return type will be `typename Derived::PlainObject`.

Comment: I guess in this case p2 would be of size (0,0) if p1 is dynamic. Is there any way you would fix the size that won't break it for fixed size matrices?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do if the documentation does not like `auto` for the return type is use trailing return type and get they type of `DerivedA * DerivedB`.  That would look like

```
inline auto mult(...) -> MatrixBase<decltype(std::declval<DerivedA>() * std::decval<DerivedB>())>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a manual solution for the first expression, in case you don't want to use C++11 or you want to be sure that the expression is actually evaluated:

```
template<class DerivedA, class DerivedB>
Eigen::Matrix<typename Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename DerivedA::Scalar, typename DerivedB::Scalar>::ReturnType, 
              DerivedA::RowsAtCompileTime, DerivedB::ColsAtCompileTime>
mult(const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedA>& p1, const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedB>& p2)
{
    return p1*p2;
}
```

`ScalarBinarayOpTraits` is used to determine if two different scalar types can be combined (e.g., `double` and `std::complex<double>`).

Example usage:

```
Eigen::Matrix3Xcd M1 = mult(Eigen::Matrix3d(), Eigen::Matrix3Xcd(3,20));
```

This is also safer, if you pass temporary objects to `mult` and store the result in an `auto` variable, e.g.:

```
double *someData = ...;
Eigen::MatrixXd someMatrix = ...; 
auto result = mult(Eigen::Matrix3d::Map(someData), someMatrix.topLeftCorner<3,4>());
```

For the second example, as ggael wrote `typename Derived::PlainObject` would be sufficient. And you can use `p2.setZero(p1.rows(), p2.cols()); to initialize`p2`;